# Как сверстать такой блок для хорошего адаптива?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как лучше всего верстать такой блок, чтобы было адаптивно? Пробовал так:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: block;
  margin: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 30%;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  top: -40px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://dapf.ru/forum/data/avatars/l/10/10483.jpg?1473624720" alt="">
</div>
```

В ширину получается, но как настраивать высоту в таком случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать при помощи `::after` и задать тегу обертки `img`, то есть `<div class="photo">` фиксированую ширину, а высоту автоматическую. Тегу `<img>` задать ширину в 100%. Вот пример:

```css
body {
 margin: 50px;
}
.photo {
 position: relative;
 width: 250px;
 height: auto;
}
.photo::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border: 3px solid #dedede;
 top: 10px;
 left: 15px;
}
.photo > img {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
  <img src="http://dapf.ru/forum/data/avatars/l/10/10483.jpg?1473624720" alt="">
</div>
```